# Preventing evaluation of $Exp[\pm i\pi]$ until the end of a calculation

Tags: evaluation, hold

I'd like to prevent Mathematica from evaluating $Exp[\pm i\ \pi]$=-1 until I tell it to, at the very end of a calculation. I have a lengthy expression that involves things like (-x+y)^(n), and I *know* that the minus sign is *either* an `Exp[I Pi]` or an `Exp[-I*Pi]`, but I don't know which. Finding that out is important for my purposes.

It would be extremely useful if there was some command like `HoldForm[Exp[I Pi]]` that worked globally for the entire notebook, inactivating `Exp[I*Pi]` until I do something like `ReleaseHold[Exp[I Pi]]` at the end.

Does there exist such a command?

Comment: This kinda does it and kinda doesn't, maybe. The problem is not well-defined yet: `Unprotect[Power];
Power[E, I Pi] = \[Zeta];
Power[E, -I Pi] = 1/\[Zeta];
Protect[Power];`. To get the numerical value, use `expr /. \[Zeta] -> -1`. This resets Mma: `Unprotect[Power];
Power[E, I Pi] =.;
Power[E, -I Pi] =.;
Protect[Power];`. If it doesn't work, then I can't help without seeing the code for which it fails.

Comment: Why not just enter it as `e^(-I*Pi)`, leaving `e` undefined, and then do `expr /. e -> E` at the end? That will even allow automatic algebraic simplifications along the way, if that's desirable.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f := Hold[Exp[I Pi]]
```

And once you want you can do

```
f // ReleaseHold
```

Edit:

addressing the comment. In the results one can do something like

```
Exp[I Pi] + m /. Exp[I Pi] -> f
```

> ```
> f + m
> ```

and then use the suggested solution

Comment: Thanks that's helpful - but is there no way of declaring that I don't want e^i\pi to be evaluated (eg) at the beginning of the notebook, such that whenever I input e^i\pi, the output is just e^i\pi? Something like HoldForm[e^i\pi], but the action of this mythical command lasts for the entirety of the notebook until I turn it off?

Comment: @Ali you can use what I suggested at the beginning of the notebook and then use `f` instead of `Exp[I Pi]`. It will remain unevaluated until your `ReleaseHold`

Comment: Ah - but the Exp[I Pi]'s that appear are the result of an integral (which I do by applying the residue theorem) - so because I never actually *see* them, I can't interfere halfway through the evaluation of the integral and replace them with f's before they are evaluated by Mathematica. At least, I don't think so?

Comment: Unless I can tell mathematica to replace every instance of Exp[I*Pi] that appears in any calculation by f?

Comment: @Ali please see the edit and let me know if it works now :)

Comment: @Ali You describe your process in the first comment as "I input e^i\pi" and in the second as "I never actually see them, I can't interfere halfway through the evaluation of the integral."  This is an important condition for solving the problem. If you never see them, how do you know `Exp[I Pi]` is generated? Or `Exp[-I Pi]` Mma might just bypass the exponential function and use `-1` right off the bat. Or it might be `Power[E, I Pi]` and not `Exp`. It's a difficult problem, and how you set up your code is probably very important to finding a solution (i.e., post an example in code).